# Creating PDF file using byte array c#/asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation

Can anybody tell me how to create a PDF file using byte array?  I tried these two methods but no luck.

```
1) System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytesArray);
2) using (System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
   {
     stream.Write(bytesArray, 0, bytesArray.Length);
   }
```

Or I need to use any 3rd party component to do the same.

Any help will be appreciated... Thanks in advance.

Comment: use [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this - *untested*

```
Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=data.pdf");
Response.BufferOutput = true; byte[] pdf; Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", response.Length.ToString());
 Response.BinaryWrite(pdf);
 Response.End();
```